# How to multiply row-vector with matrix in MTJ?

Tags: java, matrix, mtj

I want to multiply a row vector `V` with a matrix `M` to get a vector `V'`, i.e.

```
V' = V * M
```

How can I do that with MTJ? The interface `Vector` doesn't seem to have a `multiply` method.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem using the property that (V * M)<sup>T</sup> = M<sup>T</sup>*V<sup>T</sup>, i.e.

```
M.transposeMult(V, resV);
```

Still, I wonder if there is a cleaner approach.